# how to use Nginx proxy_pass to a Flask APP

Tags: nginx, flask, uwsgi, proxypass

I one websites, ie. example.com. Its nginx config file is like,

```
server{
   ... 
   location /foo{
       proxy_pass http://ip_address/;
       proxy_set_header Host ip_address;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
       proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }   
   ...
}
```

For the above ip_address, I had following nginx config file of flask app,

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name ip_address; 

location = / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/pathtomysocket/x.sock;
} 
location / {
    include uwsgi_params;
    uwsgi_pass unix:/pathtomysocket/x.sock;
}
}
```

What I would like to achieve here is that, when client visits example.com/foo, it should response from the flask app, however, there is one issue that, the urls generated from the flask app don't have foo as prefix, so when click other link like /abc, it will redirect to example.com/abc rather than example.com/foo/abc. How can I acheive this result? I searched a lot but no luck, I guess it maybe relate to server name etc.. please help. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to look into your routing configuration at your FlaskApp.

Look into [Blueprints](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/tutorial/views/?highlight=blueprint#create-a-blueprint)

This is [another example](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/urlprocessors/?highlight=routing#internationalized-blueprint-urls) of blueprint usage to prefix routes

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain well since I am not navtive english speaker..   You may think there are two servers, one hosts example.com. the other one is my flask app. When visitors request example.com/foo , I want to show index page from my flask app( the route '/'), which works fine. But when clicking other links on this page, since the url is generated from url_for, the link is like /abc/123 without domain name, so it will visit the previous server with 404,  since url should be example.com/foo/abc/123 rather than  example.com/abc/123. If I add foo manully, it can render right page as expected

Comment: as long as your backend generate the html/json with links inside, majority of times it based on the defined routes inside your app, and use that as the source of truth. You may define a ENV variable or your app configuration variable, which can work as a prefix. And if you run multiple copies of the app and need different prefixes for each (or maybe don't need to prefix for some app) you just put a proper value into that variable